# custom diagonal background texture

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a background texture rectangle block behind the charts blue rectangles. I need to create a pattern block and apply it to the fill for the grey rectangles

https://jsfiddle.net/aLh9d51t/

I currently have a solid block
[image]

but need to add a texture like this
https://iros.github.io/patternfills/sample_d3.html

[image]

```
var def = svg.append('defs').attr("height", 10).attr("width", 10).append('pattern')
```

I have to create this def

```
<svg height="10" width="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> <defs> <pattern id="diagonal-stripe-1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10"> <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxMCcgaGVpZ2h0PScxMCc+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9JzEwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzEwJyBmaWxsPSd3aGl0ZScvPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9J00tMSwxIGwyLC0yCiAgICAgICAgICAgTTAsMTAgbDEwLC0xMAogICAgICAgICAgIE05LDExIGwyLC0yJyBzdHJva2U9J2JsYWNrJyBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9JzEnLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"> </image> </pattern> </defs> </svg>



var itemRects2 = main.append('g').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');
var itemRects = main.append('g').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');

var currentLine = main
    .append('line')
    .attr('class', 'currentLine')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');

var brush = d3
    .brushX()
    .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [w, miniHeight],
    ])
    .on('brush', brushed);

mini.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x brush')
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x1.range());

function getXAxisTop(tTick, tFormat) {
    return d3
        .axisBottom(xTop)
        .ticks(d3[tTick])
        .tickFormat(d => d3.timeFormat(tFormat)(d));
}

function toDays(d) {
    d = d || 0;
    return d / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000;
}

function toUTC(d) {
    if (!d || !d.getFullYear) return 0;
    return Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
}

function daysBetween(d1, d2) {
    return toDays(toUTC(d2) - toUTC(d1));
}

function drawBrush(minExtent, maxExtent) {
    var visItems = items.filter(function(d) {
        return d.starting_time < maxExtent && d.ending_time > minExtent;
    });



    var days = daysBetween(minExtent, maxExtent);

    console.log('days', days);

    /*
    function timeFormat(formats) {
        return function(date) {
            var i = formats.length - 1, f = formats[i];
            while (!f[1](date)) f = formats[--i];
            return d3.functor(f[0])(date);
        };
    }*/

    /*
    var customTimeFormat = timeFormat([
        ["00:00", function () { return true; }],
        ["06:00", function (d) { return 3 <= d.getHours() && d.getHours() < 9; }],
        ["12:00", function (d) { return 9 <= d.getHours() && d.getHours() < 15; }],
        ["18:00", function (d) { return 15 <= d.getHours() && d.getHours() < 21; }]
    ]);
    */

    var tFormat1 = '%Y-%m';
    var tTick1 = 'timeMonth';

    //var tFormat2 = '%H%M';
    //var tTick2 = 'timeHour';

    if (days < 40) {
        tFormat1 = '%Y-%m-%d';
        tTick1 = 'timeWeek';
    }

    if (days <= 7) {
        tFormat1 = '%Y-%m-%d';
        tTick1 = 'timeDay';
    }

    if (days <= 1) {
        tFormat1 = '%H%M';
        tTick1 = 'timeHour';

        //tFormat2 = '%H%M';
        //tTick2 = customTimeFormat;
        //console.log("CUSTOM FORMAT", customTimeFormat)
    }

    var toolTipDateFormat = d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m');

    x1.domain([minExtent, maxExtent]);
    xTop.domain([minExtent, maxExtent]);
    gXTop.call(getXAxisTop(tTick1, tFormat1));
    gXTop.selectAll('.tick text');

    //gXTop2.call(getXAxisTop(tTick2, tFormat2));
    //gXTop2.selectAll('.tick text');

    currentLine
        .attr('x1', x1(now))
        .attr('x2', x1(now))
        .attr('y1', 0)
        .attr('y2', mainHeight);


    //update main item rects
    var rects = itemRects
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(visItems, function(d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x1(d.starting_time);
        })
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);
        });

    rects
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', function(d) {
            return 'miniItem';
        })
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x1(d.starting_time);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
            return y1(d.lane + gutter);
        })
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);
        })
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            return y1(1 - 2 * gutter);
        })
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
            tooltipTimeline
                .transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style('opacity', 0.9);
            tooltipTimeline
                .html(
                    'Start Time ' +
                        toolTipDateFormat(d.starting_time) +
                        '<br>' +
                        'End Time ' +
                        toolTipDateFormat(d.ending_time),
                )
                .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 'px')
                .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 28 + 'px');
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d) {
            tooltipTimeline
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .style('opacity', 0);
        });

    rects.exit().remove();



    //textured blocks
    console.log("w", w);

    //update main item rects
    var backRects = itemRects2
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(visItems, function(d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return 0;
        })
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return w;
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            return "grey";
        });


    backRects
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', function(d) {
            return 'miniItem2';
        })
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return 0;
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
            return y1(d.lane + gutter);
        })
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return w;
        })
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            return y1(1 - 2 * gutter);
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            return "grey";
        });

   // backRects.exit().remove();

    //textured block


}
```

something like this.

```
chart.append("defs").append("pattern")
    .attr('id','diagonal-stripe-1')
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr('patternUnits',"userSpaceOnUse")
    .append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href','data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxMCcgaGVpZ2h0PScxMCc+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9JzEwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzEwJyBmaWxsPSd3aGl0ZScvPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9J00tMSwxIGwyLC0yCiAgICAgICAgICAgTTAsMTAgbDEwLC0xMAogICAgICAgICAgIE05LDExIGwyLC0yJyBzdHJva2U9J2JsYWNrJyBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9JzEnLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==')
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10);
```

but how do I make it closer to the design -- custom image?

[image]

```
    //update main item rects
    var backRects = itemRects2
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(visItems, function(d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return 0;
        })
        .attr('width', function(d) {
            return w;
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            //return "grey";//'diagonal-stripe-1'
            return  "url(#diagonal-stripe-1)";
        });
```